# How can I auto-insert the document path automatically into a new Word Document

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Word 2010.  I want to automatically show the document path in the footer of a Word document after it is saved.  Is there a way to automate this.

I have looked into inserting the Word field into normal.dotm for it but it inserts as text not as a fields so the new document is showing the path to normal.dotm not itself.

Somehow this should have been easier than this.  I cannot figure it out despite 45 minutes of googling.

Seth

Answer (score 0):

doing this: http://www.ehow.com/how_5843663_add-file-location-word-document.html
then this: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-a-template-based-on-a-word-2010-docu.html

doesn't have the desired effect?

Comment: If you put the information in the answer so that it isn't a link-only answer, the OP might accept it ;)