# Add network path to the top of Word page

Tags: microsoft-word

What would I have to do to add the full network path to the top of a Microsoft Word 2013 document? Currently, it just shows the document name, and I would want the full network address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I auto-insert the document path automatically into a new Word Document](https://superuser.com/q/210238)

Answer (score 0):

There's no option in the Office applications to do it. But apparently you can do it by employing some macro's. See: http://word.tips.net/T001248_Full_Path_Names_in_Word.html

Good luck!